# Flask app using SSLify served with Apache doesn't work with https

Tags: python, apache, ssl, flask

I am running a Flask application in apache webserver  with mod_wsgi. The   app works perfectly fine when I use http. I want to access it over https, so I used the Flask-SSLify extension. Accessing the page with http redirects to https, but shows "This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect." Why isn't https working?

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sslify import SSLify

app = Flask(__name__)
sslify = SSLify(app)
```

Comment: Is Apache configured for HTTPS?

Comment: @dirn   not sure, could   you please  share a    link for  configuring HTTPS  in windows 7.? Is there   something  I need  to do on the  flask part?

Comment: It depends more on your Apache version than your operating system, but the [Apache docs provide a how-to](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html).